# Lightweight physics engine Android

Tags: java, android, game-physics

I'm looking for a lightweight physics engine for Android. I don't want it to do any rendering itself. It needs to be easy to use, fast, and have some tutorials/api docs.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what is lightweight physics engine ?

Comment: So very basic,not to many unessesary stuff,so no rendering built in,things like that

Comment: Box2D is the main one, but as the name indicate, it's 2D.  It has been ported to many languages, including javascript. AngryBird uses it.

Comment: Yeah,ive been looking at box2d,but all the tuts i find are outof date :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while back ago and eventually decided to go with JBox2D: http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/.

I agree that docs are not very good for this particular port, however I find the original manual very useful (despite the fact that it's in C++): http://www.box2d.org/manual.html.

Furthermore, JBox2D comes with something that is called Testbed -- a simple GUI application aimed for testing. It has a bunch of examples, which should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

[Libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) has [JBox2D](http://www.jbox2d.org/) built in and is cross platform (Android, Java Desktop, GWT Web) like Unity, tho it's free and [open source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/). Not sure why you don't want the library to do rendering for you, but you can strip out anything you don't want.